# Memory leak in C# winforms app on picturebox

Tags: c#, image, winforms, memory-leaks, idisposable

my application reads frames from a video (does some processing) and then displays it in a picture box - this is done around 10 times a second and i have now ran into a problem where the picturebox image is not being disposed of correctly.

I get a memory leakage and eventually an out of memory exception.

```
   //Check if PictureBox already contains an image, if so dispose of it.
if (VideoDisplay.Image != null)
{
    VideoDisplay.Image.Dispose();
}
   //set parameter to the new image
displayImage = OverlayImage.UpdateImage(eventArgs.Frame, WarningText, WarningBrush);
   //set the picturebox to the new image
VideoDisplay.Image = displayImage;
   //dispose of brush & start garbage collector
WarningBrush.Dispose();
GC.Collect();
```

By commenting out the `VideoDisplay.Image = displayImage` line the memory leakage stops (but obviously i get no image).

Just wondered if anyone could give me a hand with this as i have never before worked with disposing of objects etc and dont know if i have made a mistake in disposing or have missed something out.

Comment: what happens here `OverlayImage.UpdateImage`?

Comment: 1. Why are you disposing the brush here? Clearly this code is not allocating the brush, where is that code? 2. What does `OverlayImage.UpdateImage(...)` do? Can you show the code for that method? 3. You should pull the image of the picturebox out of the picturebox before you dispose of it, by grabbing it into a local variable and setting the Image property of the picturebox to null first. 4. Are you sure reassigning the `Image` property of the picturebox won't dispose of the existing image by itself (I have no idea, would need to check)?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen for point 4, it does not.

Comment: I am disposing of the brush here as it is the last time it is used, as i thought that was the right way of doing it, if not please correct me. The OverlayImage.UpdateImage() bassically adds an overlay to the current frame and passes back an Image, i can get the code later (as im not at my computer), but i have tried setting displayImage = eventArgs.Frame instead which still causes a memory leak. I will try point 3 that you raised later and let you know my results. Thanks for the feedback it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Before you update image, you need to dispose it. I had similar problem.
**Like so:**

```
VideoDisplay.Image.Dispose();
```

After that line of code, update the image.
**For your scenario:**

```
VideoDisplay.Image = displayImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer turned out by removing the VideoDisplay.Dispose() it fixed it.
By having a quick look up on this there may have been a lock put on the object which the GC cannot then collect.